# Define timeout for XMLA requests in iccube

Tags: iccube, xmla

Is there a way to define a timeout for xmla requests in IcCube ?

Very long requests may use all the resources and should be killed to avoid that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  section within the icCube.xml file allows for defining processing "profiles" per user, per role, etc... A profile can for example limits the number of threads used to process an MDX query. Another possibility is to define a "timeout".

You can have a look to the file that is explaining in details what can be configured.

Hope that helps.